# aws deployment, web app on ec2 and ms sql db on RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have deployed .net web application on EC2 instance and database on RDS.
what are the changes i need to make in my application so that web app can access database which is on RDS.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of checklist that you need to do.

- Make sure your AWS RDS Security Group(SG) **InBound Rules** allows your EC2 traffic to pass through. You can refer to the below Screenshots on how to navigate to RDS SG
- Make sure that your RDS DB Instance is in status **"Available"**
- Lastly, make sure you have the right Db adapter in your application code that will initiate the connection.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have done that but still not working. Any changes needed at the code like DB connection string?

Comment: The best way to check is to know what is the error returned by your application. You can catch it by your application library that connect to the DB. From there you will know where the error occurs (is it on the client side, DB network side .e.g denied connection)